# Saving field result of aggregation unwind in collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need save the field idOriginAccount in collection banking_atendimento.
the result of aggregate operation returns

[image: two muppets]

I'm using robo3t to make the query

see the query

```
    db.getCollection('banking_atendimento').aggregate([{   
    $lookup:{
        from:"banking_ted",
        localField:"idtransacao",
        foreignField:"id",
        as:"transacao",
       }
},
{$unwind: '$transacao'},
])
```

What operator i do use to insert the field in collection "banking_ted"

Comment: You may try [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) or [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/). Normally, aggregation is used to group, change, cross data and / or store them in other collection

Answer (score 0):

As Andrews suggested, you can use $out to write to a new collection. 
Here's the complete query for you

```
db.getCollection('banking_atendimento').aggregate([{   
    $lookup:{
            from:"banking_ted",
            localField:"idtransacao",
            foreignField:"id",
            as:"transacao",
           }
    },
    {$unwind: '$transacao'},
    {$out: 'banking_ted'}
])
```